# Transforming list of hashmaps into set

Tags: clojure

Having two maps:

```
(def a {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
(def b {:b 222 :d 4})
```

placed into one vector:

```
(def l [a b])
```

what's the easiest way to construct a set (in terms of structure of unique keys) where the priority in case of key conflict (:b in this case) has a left-hand operand (:b 2 in this case). In other words I'd like to get a result:

```
{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4}
```

Two solutions which came to mind mind are:

```
(apply merge-with (fn [left _] left) l)
(reduce conj (reverse l))
```

First one doesn't seem idiomatic for me, second one worries me because of eager list reversing which sounds a bit inneficient. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the first solution. Why it is not idiomatic?

Comment: go with second solution. if you have long list - consider replacing reverse with lazy rseq.

Comment: @m0skit0 throwing all elements into a "merge" function which doesn't really care about both arguments (just returns a first one) makes me feel a bit uncomfortable :)

Comment: @iced I didn't know about rseq. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerous other possibilities of which `(reduce #(into %2 %1) l)` (or with `merge` instead of `into`) could be considered. Your `merge-with` solution is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`(apply merge (reverse l))`

it's seems fine and simular to second one.

Comment: thanks, but still it tries to reverse list in a meantime. I'm gonna use this function with quite a long list of maps and reversing it first sounds scary :)

Comment: If you use `rseq` instead, that's constant time on vectors. But surely reversing a two element collection won't be any sort of bottleneck.